# c# logging framework - logfiles with explicit names

Tags: c#, logging, frameworks

I´m searching for a logging framework for c# where I can set the logfile name easy from code.

My program starts several background workers which all should log into their own log files. 
They use the same classes for their work and sometimes in different threads.

e.g.

```html
backgroundworker1:
    var aboImport = new CSVImport(file1);        <-- logs into backgroundWorker1.log
    aboImport.Execute();
    ArchiveFile(file1);
 
 backgroundworker2:
 var addressImport = new CSVImport(file2);        <-- logs into backgroundWorker2.log
 addressImport.Execute();
 ArchiveFile(file2);
 
e.g.

backgroundWorker1.log
backgroundWorker2.log
backgroundWorker3.log
...

heartbeat.log                   <-- I´can see my workers or main thread is running an working
```

I´m using using log4net at the moment, but this does not seem to fit my needs.
I found ([Create multiple Logfiles with dynamic Names with log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33095366/create-multiple-logfiles-with-dynamic-names-with-log4net)) where they create dynamic appenders in code.
But I do not understand whow this works, because the log4net definitions are normally tied to the namespaces. 
Can other logging frameworks do this more elegant? Which logging framework do you recommend for this?

Comment: Log4net is best logger on the market. It's complex but you can use simple configuration too.

Comment: @P.K., lol... its not even supported anymore. Last release was a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nlog I could easy create loggers with different file targets.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = LogManager.Configuration;
    AddLogger(config, "logger1", @"C:\Temp\Logfile\Log1.txt");
    AddLogger(config, "logger2", @"C:\Temp\Logfile\Log2.txt");
    LogManager.Configuration = config;

    var logger1 = LogManager.GetLogger("logger1");
    logger1.Debug("Test1");

    var logger2 = LogManager.GetLogger("logger2");
    logger2.Debug("Test2");
}

private static void AddLogger(LoggingConfiguration config, string loggerName, string fileName)
{
    var fileTarget = new FileTarget();
    config.AddTarget(loggerName, fileTarget);
    fileTarget.FileName = fileName;

    var rule = new LoggingRule(loggerName, LogLevel.Debug, fileTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
}
```

Comment: Recently we also added `config.AddRule` to make it easier and shorter to add/create a NLog rule

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from Log4Net. It's not an actively developed project. Last release was almost 1 yr ago (12/2015). NLog is much better supported.

With that being said, all the logging frameworks let you do everything template driven with a bunch of different "macros"... you might base the filename on threadId or some other dynamic value... or just pass it in through a key/value pair. You have to look at all the "macros" available and pick the one that works in your scenario.

Comment: What is the problem that is not activley developed. When it has all feauters of a logging framework an works smooth? .. I cannot tie the filename on the threadId, because there is no guarantee that all code runs in the same thread. I need to set the filename to the instance of the object so it can log explicit in this file.

Comment: @JohnnyBravo75 you want to use abandoned projects up to you :) all the logging frameworks have the same features and work the same pretty much. Nlog is the most active. As I said there are many macros you can choose from to build your filename dynamically.